# File created under subshell does not keep subshell's umask setting

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to understand why subshell setting will be discard.

Under the subshell:

```
export UMASK=000 && touch output.file
```

Then back to the parent shell to output into output.file
But output.file has inherited parent shell's `UMASK=007`

Comment: By `output into output.file`, do you mean `write to output.file`

Comment: Unless you have some weird version of `touch`, then the `UMASK` environmnent variable will have no effect on the execution of `touch`.   You could try adding `ls -al output.file` to the end of your subshell's command to confirm.

Answer (score 3):

Never heard of such an environment variable, use `umask` command instead:

```
umask 000 && touch output.file
```